# Eclipse and Maven configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I'm new to Maven. I've just installed and configured it. 
When I started coding, I realized Eclipse doesn't show the error messages. 
I haven't found anything helpful by searching Google. Some sources say to add java builder to your project but I already did.

Here's a [screenshot](http://d1202.hizliresim.com/u/r/2yxw1.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks, that you had project in eclipse configured to have source code in 'src' subdirectory (and compile classes to 'bin').
Maven by default looks for java sources in src/main/java (and compile classes to 'target/classes').
So you'd need to move your source code to src/main/java or modify pom.xml to point to 'src' as source directory.
I'd suggest following maven convention and store source code in src/main/java.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't create the Maven standard folder structure.
Create the structure like that:
src/main/java for Java classes and src/main/resources for properties etc., then do a right click on the project and choose Maven -> Update project configuration.